# rank of block matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C^{n\times n}}$ is invertible. Then: $M =\begin{pmatrix}A&I\\I&X\end{pmatrix}$ $ \in \mathbb{C^{2n\times 2n}}$ has the same rank as $A$ if and only if $X = A^{-1}$ .

What happens if $A \in \mathbb{C^{n\times n}}$ is singular?

Any hint please.

Comment: With $n=1$ (and of course $A$=0), we can see that whatever $X$ is, the new matrix will have rank $2$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but we have that $\det(M)=\det(AX-I)=\det(XA-I)$, regardless of whether $A$ is or isn't invertible (see, for instance, [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)). This means that whenever $AX$ does not have $1$ as an eigevalue, then $M$ will necessarily be invertible and hence full-rank.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So their rank are different by taking your counter example.  
i.e.' With $n=1$  and A=0,  whatever $X $is, the new matrix $M$ will have rank 2'.